# Apache require valid-user only working with one url on same directory

Tags: linux, web-server, authentication, apache-2.4

I have a directory "/var/www/web" and i configured .htaccess and htpasswd to require a valid user to access web. Also, i have a web.conf file on sites-enabled directory and serverName web.server.com.

If i try to access website with "web.server.com" access is restricted and have to enter credentials. But, if i try to access website with server.com/web url i can access the web without authentication.

What i'm doing wrong?

```
<VirtualHost *******:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName web.server.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/web">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow From All
    </Directory>
```

htaccess:

```
# Apache/PHP settings:
#

#Access
AuthUserFile /var/www/web/.htpasswd
AuthName " Acceso restringido”
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sites `web.server.com` and `server.com/web` are two different sites. When you access them, they may point to the same directory but apache uses two different files for their configuration. You have the `.httaccess` enabled for the virtual site `web.server.com` and not for the  `server.com` site. That's why one is working and the other not.

To solve the problem, add the same configuration for the `/var/www/web` directory in the `server.com` site config and see. It should work.

You should also update the following entry for correct syntax for Apache 2.4:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Should be something like:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

You will need to adjust it to your need. Note the `+/-` sign, which enables or disables an option.

Comment: I tried, but not working. I already had AllowOverride AuthConfig for directory. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your virtual host config file content?

Comment: Comment or disable this part `<Directory /> 
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>`and try again.

Comment: I tried but it is the same. Can be related with folder permissions?

Comment: What is your `.htaccess` file content? Please post it too.

Comment: Yes, i added config to server config and it works. Thank you :)